# Blockly : Equivalent of pause in time ? ( In JS it is setTimout )

Tags: javascript, timeout, settimeout, blockly

What if I wish to pause for a few seconds in Blockly ? How to do this with the Blockly blocks ? (The equivalent in Javascript is setTimeout.)

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer from another Forum. The latest answer to this question is :

"We don't provide a block that does this, but you could make one if you are using the JS interpretter to run your generated JavaScript."

This was answered in :
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/blockly/timeout%7Csort:relevance/blockly/5xbDQ8FQzbI/78lJenyPEQAJ